# Are "till" and "until" perfectly interchangeable at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions, word-position

In the following sentences, would one of these conjunctions sound better than the other?

> - *Until/Till* my daughter got married, I had never been abroad.
> - *Until/Till* you change your mind, I won't help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Oxford Dictionaries the answer is yes they are interchangeable, but they also offer some style advice about word selection that indicates you might be better off chosing "Until."

> [till](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/till)
>   - Less formal way of saying until.
>
> **Usage**
>
> In most contexts, till and until have the same meaning and are
>   interchangeable. The main difference is that till is generally
>   considered to be more informal than until. Until occurs much more
>   frequently than till in writing. In addition, **until tends to be the
>   natural choice at the beginning of a sentence**: until very recently,
>   there was still a chance of rescuing the situation. Interestingly,
>   while it is commonly assumed that till is an abbreviated form of until
>   (the spellings ‘till and ’til reflect this), till is in fact the
>   earlier form. Until appears to have been formed by the addition of Old
>   Norse und (‘as far as’) several hundred years after the date of the
>   first records for till.

(emphasis mine)